# Use different versions of Bootstrap css on the same page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to use a Bootstrap CSS in 4.6 as global level for every page, but on a section of one page, we need to use a 3rd party tool that uses Bootstrap CSS 3.7. Upgrading to 4.6 breaks the 3rd party tool.

Is it possible to make both versions coexist without affecting other sections of the page?

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: Am not sure. MAybe if you separate them and call them from different files but that will depend on which other langauges are involved. if its purely HTML or not

Comment: can you show an example, if it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

Frameworks are consistent software that needs CSS + JS working together to get results.

In another hand, BS4 changes a lot against BS3.

So, the short answer is NO.